# Welcome message after filling a form

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out the code where I want the user of my website to fill a form and after submitting the form he/she gets a welcome message on the same sign-up page, not on a different page. Below is my code using `innerHTML`.

```
<script>
  function displayGreeting(){
    let name = document.getElementById(‘usrname’).value;
    document.getElementById(‘outputDiv’).innerHTML = “Hello” + usrname +
      “, Welcome to Livewell page <br/>” +
      “You are officially a livewell member “ + usrname + “!”;
  }
</script>
```

```
<center><input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="displayGreeting()"/></center>
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You define `name`, never use it, but go ahead and use the undefined `usrname`? And what about the smart quotes `“` `”`? Have you used the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors?

Comment: I am unable to find a lottery ticket for the current drawing that has all of the numbers correctly chosen.

Comment: @Xufox, hey I have replaced name by usrname but its still giving me the same value, it wouldn't show the message

Comment: for my project I am only allowed to use javascript and HTML, is there any way i can use these two languages only? @JonathanLonowski

Comment: @Zena AJAX isn’t a language. You can use AJAX in JS, though this is probably not necessarily what you need.

Comment: @Xufox I still didn't study about AJAX in JS, but I've made my research on the code for a welcome message but all I'm getting is a pop-up alert and that's not what I actually need for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You had some invalid characters in your code like `‘`, `’`, `“`, `”`. Remember to use `'` or `"`
- Your `br` tag was mistyped, it has to be `<br>`
- You where missing an input field for your username
- You wanted to use variable `name` to output the username, but some lines beneath, you use `usrname`

```js
function displayGreeting() {
  let usrname = document.getElementById('usrname').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + usrname + ', Welcome to Livewell page' + '<br> ' + 'You are officially a livewell member ' + usrname + '!';
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="usrname">
<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="displayGreeting()" /></center>
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

---

If you want to display the message submitting while staying on the same page, you will need to prevent the forms default action: submitting.

```js
function displayGreeting(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let usrname = document.getElementById('usrname').value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + usrname + ', Welcome to Livewell page' + '<br> ' + 'You are officially a livewell member ' + usrname + '!';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="displayGreeting(event)">
  <input type="input" id="usrname">
  <input type="submit" value="Create" /></center>
  <hr>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</form>
```

Note that the data won't get submitted then. So if you want data to be sent to the back end, you will need to do this in a different way.

Comment: Hi @CodeF0x, the code you edited is partially working, but the welcome message only appears when I click create without filling the form and it's not displaying the the welcome message when I fill the form and click submit. maybe there's more to be added to the script to fix that.

Comment: `<br/>` is a form of HTML syntax called XHTML and while I personally don't advocate for its use, it is allowable.

Comment: Thank you so much @CodeF0x, the code you edited worked pretty well!

Comment: @Zena Glad to help!